LEFT JOIN in sqldf is inappropriately filtering on a WHERE condition
I am using sqldf to left join a data dictionary onto a field of responses. I'd like to create a condition where it only joins when certain fields are not null, but I don't want to filter those out (which is why I'm doing a left join in the first place!). Without the WHERE condition, everything is fine:
screening_data_responses_test <- sqldf("select *
      FROM screening_data_responses v
      LEFT JOIN data_dictionary_qonly i 
                       on i.lql_id=v.question_id")

but when I add my WHERE condition, it filters out all rows that don't meet the WHERE condition:
screening_data_responses_test <- sqldf("select *
      FROM screening_data_responses v
      LEFT JOIN data_dictionary_qonly i 
                       on i.lql_id=v.question_id
                       WHERE v.response_char IS NOT NULL or v.response_num IS NOT NULL")

I know that the WHERE is in the wrong place, and it's being applied after the join has already happened, which is why it's filtering. But I cannot figure out where to move it to or what I should use instead. How can I modify my code so that the rows with nulls in both v.response_char and v.response_num are NOT joined, but REMAIN in the dataframe (with nulls in the respective columns from data_dictionary_qonly)?

The usual approach is to move the conditions from the WHERE clause to the JOIN clause:
screening_data_responses_test <- sqldf("select *
  FROM screening_data_responses v
  LEFT JOIN data_dictionary_qonly i 
         ON i.lql_id=v.question_id
        AND v.response_char IS NOT NULL 
        AND v.response_num IS NOT NULL
")

(untested, I don't have an R installation readily available)

I was testing a similar solution I think at the exact same time as you were posting this :) I replaced the WHERE with an AND (because I don't need BOTH of those variables to not be null, only at least one), and it worked swimmingly. Thank you!!

Just solved my issue! Changed the WHERE to an AND and everything fixed itself.
screening_data_responses_test <- sqldf("select *
      FROM screening_data_responses v
      LEFT JOIN data_dictionary_qonly i 
                       on i.lql_id=v.question_id
                                 AND (v.response_char IS NOT NULL or v.response_num IS NOT NULL)")

